# i need to find the coordinated of the peaks as well as delineate their boundaries (i.e. peak 1 begins at time 65 and ends at time 71)

Tags: numpy, scipy, width

```
import numpy, sys 
from matplotlib import pyplot 
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths

t=[0.0, 0.187, 0.373, 0.56, 0.747, 0.933, 1.12, 1.307, 1.493, 1.68, 1.867, 2.053, 2.24, 2.427, 2.613, 2.8, 2.987, 3.173, 3.36, 3.547, 3.733, 3.92, 4.107, 4.293, 4.48, 4.667, 4.853, 5.04, 5.227, 5.413, 5.6, 5.787, 5.973, 6.16, 6.347, 6.533, 6.72, 6.907, 7.093, 7.28, 7.467, 7.653, 7.84, 8.027, 8.213, 8.4, 8.587, 8.773, 8.96, 9.147, 9.333, 9.52, 9.707, 9.893, 10.08, 10.267, 10.453, 10.64, 10.827, 11.013, 11.2, 11.387, 11.573, 11.76, 11.947, 12.133, 12.32, 12.507, 12.693, 12.88, 13.067, 13.253, 13.44, 13.627, 13.813, 14.0, 14.187, 14.373, 14.56, 14.747, 14.933, 15.12, 15.307, 15.493, 15.68, 15.867, 16.053, 16.24, 16.427, 16.613, 16.8, 16.987, 17.173, 17.36, 17.547, 17.733, 17.92, 18.107, 18.293, 18.48, 18.667, 18.853, 19.04, 19.227, 19.413, 19.6, 19.787, 19.973, 20.16, 20.347, 20.533, 20.72, 20.907, 21.093, 21.28, 21.467, 21.653, 21.84, 22.027, 22.213, 22.4, 22.587, 22.773, 22.96, 23.147, 23.333, 23.52, 23.707, 23.893, 24.08, 24.267, 24.453, 24.64, 24.827, 25.013, 25.2, 25.387, 25.573, 25.76, 25.947, 26.133, 26.32, 26.507, 26.693, 26.88, 27.067, 27.253, 27.44, 27.627, 27.813, 28.0, 28.187, 28.373, 28.56, 28.747, 28.933, 29.12, 29.307, 29.493, 29.68, 29.867, 30.053, 30.24, 30.427, 30.613, 30.8, 30.987, 31.173, 31.36, 31.547, 31.733, 31.92, 32.107, 32.293, 32.48, 32.667, 32.853, 33.04, 33.227, 33.413, 33.6, 33.787, 33.973, 34.16, 34.347, 34.533, 34.72, 34.907, 35.093, 35.28, 35.467, 35.653, 35.84, 36.027, 36.213, 36.4, 36.587, 36.773, 36.96, 37.147, 37.333, 37.52, 37.707, 37.893, 38.08, 38.267, 38.453, 38.64, 38.827, 39.013, 39.2, 39.387, 39.573, 39.76, 39.947, 40.133, 40.32, 40.507, 40.693, 40.88, 41.067, 41.253, 41.44, 41.627, 41.813, 42.0, 42.187, 42.373, 42.56, 42.747, 42.933, 43.12, 43.307, 43.493, 43.68, 43.867, 44.053, 44.24, 44.427, 44.613, 44.8, 44.987, 45.173, 45.36, 45.547, 45.733, 45.92, 46.107, 46.293, 46.48, 46.667, 46.853, 47.04, 47.227, 47.413, 47.6, 47.787, 47.973, 48.16, 48.347, 48.533, 48.72, 48.907, 49.093, 49.28, 49.467, 49.653, 49.84, 50.027, 50.213, 50.4, 50.587, 50.773, 50.96, 51.147, 51.333, 51.52, 51.707, 51.893, 52.08, 52.267, 52.453, 52.64, 52.827, 53.013, 53.2, 53.387, 53.573, 53.76, 53.947, 54.133, 54.32, 54.507, 54.693, 54.88, 55.067, 55.253, 55.44, 55.627, 55.813, 56.0, 56.187, 56.373, 56.56, 56.747, 56.933, 57.12, 57.307, 57.493, 57.68, 57.867, 58.053, 58.24, 58.427, 58.613, 58.8, 58.987, 59.173, 59.36, 59.547, 59.733, 59.92, 60.107, 60.293, 60.48, 60.667, 60.853, 61.04, 61.227, 61.413, 61.6, 61.787, 61.973, 62.16, 62.347, 62.533, 62.72, 62.907, 63.093, 63.28, 63.467, 63.653, 63.84, 64.027, 64.213, 64.4, 64.587, 64.773, 64.96, 65.147, 65.333, 65.52, 65.707, 65.893, 66.08, 66.267, 66.453, 66.64, 66.827, 67.013, 67.2, 67.387, 67.573, 67.76, 67.947, 68.133, 68.32, 68.507, 68.693, 68.88, 69.067, 69.253, 69.44, 69.627, 69.813, 70.0, 70.187, 70.373, 70.56, 70.747, 70.933, 71.12, 71.307, 71.493, 71.68, 71.867, 72.053, 72.24, 72.427, 72.613, 72.8, 72.987, 73.173, 73.36, 73.547, 73.733, 73.92, 74.107, 74.293, 74.48, 74.667, 74.853, 75.04, 75.227, 75.413, 75.6, 75.787, 75.973, 76.16, 76.347, 76.533, 76.72, 76.907, 77.093, 77.28, 77.467, 77.653, 77.84, 78.027, 78.213, 78.4, 78.587, 78.773, 78.96, 79.147, 79.333, 79.52, 79.707, 79.893, 80.08, 80.267, 80.453, 80.64, 80.827, 81.013, 81.2, 81.387, 81.573, 81.76, 81.947, 82.133, 82.32, 82.507, 82.693, 82.88, 83.067, 83.253, 83.44, 83.627, 83.813, 84.0, 84.187, 84.373, 84.56, 84.747, 84.933, 85.12, 85.307, 85.493, 85.68, 85.867, 86.053, 86.24, 86.427, 86.613, 86.8, 86.987, 87.173, 87.36, 87.547, 87.733, 87.92, 88.107, 88.293, 88.48, 88.667, 88.853, 89.04, 89.227, 89.413, 89.6, 89.787, 89.973, 90.16, 90.347, 90.533, 90.72, 90.907, 91.093, 91.28, 91.467, 91.653, 91.84, 92.027, 92.213, 92.4, 92.587, 92.773, 92.96, 93.147, 93.333, 93.52, 93.707, 93.893, 94.08, 94.267, 94.453, 94.64, 94.827, 95.013, 95.2, 95.387, 95.573, 95.76, 95.947, 96.133, 96.32, 96.507, 96.693, 96.88, 97.067, 97.253, 97.44, 97.627, 97.813, 98.0, 98.187, 98.373, 98.56, 98.747, 98.933, 99.12, 99.307, 99.493, 99.68, 99.867, 100.053, 100.24, 100.427, 100.613, 100.8, 100.987, 101.173, 101.36, 101.547, 101.733, 101.92, 102.107, 102.293, 102.48, 102.667, 102.853, 103.04, 103.227, 103.413, 103.6, 103.787, 103.973, 104.16, 104.347, 104.533, 104.72, 104.907, 105.093, 105.28, 105.467, 105.653, 105.84, 106.027, 106.213, 106.4, 106.587, 106.773, 106.96, 107.147, 107.333, 107.52, 107.707, 107.893, 108.08, 108.267, 108.453, 108.64, 108.827, 109.013, 109.2, 109.387, 109.573, 109.76, 109.947, 110.133, 110.32, 110.507, 110.693, 110.88, 111.067, 111.253, 111.44, 111.627, 111.813, 112.0, 112.187, 112.373, 112.56, 112.747, 112.933, 113.12, 113.307, 113.493, 113.68, 113.867, 114.053, 114.24, 114.427, 114.613, 114.8, 114.987, 115.173, 115.36, 115.547, 115.733, 115.92, 116.107, 116.293, 116.48, 116.667, 116.853, 117.04, 117.227, 117.413, 117.6, 117.787, 117.973, 118.16, 118.347, 118.533, 118.72, 118.907, 119.093, 119.28, 119.467, 119.653, 119.84, 120.027, 120.213, 120.4, 120.587, 120.773, 120.96, 121.147, 121.333, 121.52, 121.707, 121.893, 122.08, 122.267, 122.453, 122.64, 122.827, 123.013, 123.2, 123.387, 123.573, 123.76, 123.947, 124.133, 124.32, 124.507, 124.693, 124.88, 125.067, 125.253, 125.44, 125.627, 125.813, 126.0, 126.187, 126.373, 126.56, 126.747, 126.933, 127.12, 127.307, 127.493, 127.68, 127.867, 128.053, 128.24, 128.427, 128.613, 128.8, 128.987, 129.173, 129.36, 129.547, 129.733, 129.92, 130.107, 130.293, 130.48, 130.667, 130.853, 131.04, 131.227, 131.413, 131.6, 131.787, 131.973, 132.16, 132.347, 132.533, 132.72, 132.907, 133.093, 133.28, 133.467, 133.653, 133.84, 134.027, 134.213, 134.4, 134.587, 134.773, 134.96, 135.147, 135.333, 135.52, 135.707, 135.893, 136.08, 136.267, 136.453, 136.64, 136.827, 137.013, 137.2, 137.387, 137.573, 137.76, 137.947, 138.133, 138.32, 138.507, 138.693, 138.88, 139.067, 139.253, 139.44, 139.627, 139.813, 140.0, 140.187, 140.373, 140.56, 140.747, 140.933, 141.12, 141.307, 141.493, 141.68, 141.867, 142.053, 142.24, 142.427, 142.613, 142.8, 142.987, 143.173, 143.36, 143.547, 143.733, 143.92, 144.107, 144.293, 144.48, 144.667, 144.853, 145.04, 145.227, 145.413, 145.6, 145.787, 145.973, 146.16, 146.347, 146.533, 146.72, 146.907, 147.093, 147.28, 147.467, 147.653, 147.84, 148.027, 148.213, 148.4, 148.587, 148.773, 148.96, 149.147, 149.333, 149.52, 149.707, 149.893, 150.08, 150.267, 150.453, 150.64, 150.827, 151.013, 151.2, 151.387, 151.573, 151.76, 151.947, 152.133, 152.32, 152.507, 152.693, 152.88, 153.067, 153.253, 153.44, 153.627, 153.813, 154.0, 154.187, 154.373, 154.56, 154.747, 154.933, 155.12, 155.307, 155.493, 155.68, 155.867, 156.053, 156.24, 156.427, 156.613, 156.8, 156.987, 157.173, 157.36, 157.547, 157.733, 157.92, 158.107, 158.293, 158.48, 158.667, 158.853, 159.04, 159.227, 159.413, 159.6, 159.787, 159.973, 160.16, 160.347, 160.533, 160.72, 160.907, 161.093, 161.28, 161.467, 161.653, 161.84, 162.027, 162.213, 162.4, 162.587, 162.773, 162.96, 163.147, 163.333, 163.52, 163.707, 163.893, 164.08, 164.267]

a= [0.0, 0.187, 0.373, 0.56, 0.747, 0.933, 1.12, 1.307, 1.493, 1.68, 1.867, 2.053, 2.24, 2.427, 2.613, 2.8, 2.987, 3.173, 3.36, 3.547, 3.733, 3.92, 4.107, 4.293, 4.48, 4.667, 4.853, 5.04, 5.227, 5.413, 5.6, 5.787, 5.973, 6.16, 6.347, 6.533, 6.72, 6.907, 7.093, 7.28, 7.467, 7.653, 7.84, 8.027, 8.213, 8.4, 8.587, 8.773, 8.96, 9.147, 9.333, 9.52, 9.707, 9.893, 10.08, 10.267, 10.453, 10.64, 10.827, 11.013, 11.2, 11.387, 11.573, 11.76, 11.947, 12.133, 12.32, 12.507, 12.693, 12.88, 13.067, 13.253, 13.44, 13.627, 13.813, 14.0, 14.187, 14.373, 14.56, 14.747, 14.933, 15.12, 15.307, 15.493, 15.68, 15.867, 16.053, 16.24, 16.427, 16.613, 16.8, 16.987, 17.173, 17.36, 17.547, 17.733, 17.92, 18.107, 18.293, 18.48, 18.667, 18.853, 19.04, 19.227, 19.413, 19.6, 19.787, 19.973, 20.16, 20.347, 20.533, 20.72, 20.907, 21.093, 21.28, 21.467, 21.653, 21.84, 22.027, 22.213, 22.4, 22.587, 22.773, 22.96, 23.147, 23.333, 23.52, 23.707, 23.893, 24.08, 24.267, 24.453, 24.64, 24.827, 25.013, 25.2, 25.387, 25.573, 25.76, 25.947, 26.133, 26.32, 26.507, 26.693, 26.88, 27.067, 27.253, 27.44, 27.627, 27.813, 28.0, 28.187, 28.373, 28.56, 28.747, 28.933, 29.12, 29.307, 29.493, 29.68, 29.867, 30.053, 30.24, 30.427, 30.613, 30.8, 30.987, 31.173, 31.36, 31.547, 31.733, 31.92, 32.107, 32.293, 32.48, 32.667, 32.853, 33.04, 33.227, 33.413, 33.6, 33.787, 33.973, 34.16, 34.347, 34.533, 34.72, 34.907, 35.093, 35.28, 35.467, 35.653, 35.84, 36.027, 36.213, 36.4, 36.587, 36.773, 36.96, 37.147, 37.333, 37.52, 37.707, 37.893, 38.08, 38.267, 38.453, 38.64, 38.827, 39.013, 39.2, 39.387, 39.573, 39.76, 39.947, 40.133, 40.32, 40.507, 40.693, 40.88, 41.067, 41.253, 41.44, 41.627, 41.813, 42.0, 42.187, 42.373, 42.56, 42.747, 42.933, 43.12, 43.307, 43.493, 43.68, 43.867, 44.053, 44.24, 44.427, 44.613, 44.8, 44.987, 45.173, 45.36, 45.547, 45.733, 45.92, 46.107, 46.293, 46.48, 46.667, 46.853, 47.04, 47.227, 47.413, 47.6, 47.787, 47.973, 48.16, 48.347, 48.533, 48.72, 48.907, 49.093, 49.28, 49.467, 49.653, 49.84, 50.027, 50.213, 50.4, 50.587, 50.773, 50.96, 51.147, 51.333, 51.52, 51.707, 51.893, 52.08, 52.267, 52.453, 52.64, 52.827, 53.013, 53.2, 53.387, 53.573, 53.76, 53.947, 54.133, 54.32, 54.507, 54.693, 54.88, 55.067, 55.253, 55.44, 55.627, 55.813, 56.0, 56.187, 56.373, 56.56, 56.747, 56.933, 57.12, 57.307, 57.493, 57.68, 57.867, 58.053, 58.24, 58.427, 58.613, 58.8, 58.987, 59.173, 59.36, 59.547, 59.733, 59.92, 60.107, 60.293, 60.48, 60.667, 60.853, 61.04, 61.227, 61.413, 61.6, 61.787, 61.973, 62.16, 62.347, 62.533, 62.72, 62.907, 63.093, 63.28, 63.467, 63.653, 63.84, 64.027, 64.213, 64.4, 64.587, 64.773, 64.96, 65.147, 65.333, 65.52, 65.707, 65.893, 66.08, 66.267, 66.453, 66.64, 66.827, 67.013, 67.2, 67.387, 67.573, 67.76, 67.947, 68.133, 68.32, 68.507, 68.693, 68.88, 69.067, 69.253, 69.44, 69.627, 69.813, 70.0, 70.187, 70.373, 70.56, 70.747, 70.933, 71.12, 71.307, 71.493, 71.68, 71.867, 72.053, 72.24, 72.427, 72.613, 72.8, 72.987, 73.173, 73.36, 73.547, 73.733, 73.92, 74.107, 74.293, 74.48, 74.667, 74.853, 75.04, 75.227, 75.413, 75.6, 75.787, 75.973, 76.16, 76.347, 76.533, 76.72, 76.907, 77.093, 77.28, 77.467, 77.653, 77.84, 78.027, 78.213, 78.4, 78.587, 78.773, 78.96, 79.147, 79.333, 79.52, 79.707, 79.893, 80.08, 80.267, 80.453, 80.64, 80.827, 81.013, 81.2, 81.387, 81.573, 81.76, 81.947, 82.133, 82.32, 82.507, 82.693, 82.88, 83.067, 83.253, 83.44, 83.627, 83.813, 84.0, 84.187, 84.373, 84.56, 84.747, 84.933, 85.12, 85.307, 85.493, 85.68, 85.867, 86.053, 86.24, 86.427, 86.613, 86.8, 86.987, 87.173, 87.36, 87.547, 87.733, 87.92, 88.107, 88.293, 88.48, 88.667, 88.853, 89.04, 89.227, 89.413, 89.6, 89.787, 89.973, 90.16, 90.347, 90.533, 90.72, 90.907, 91.093, 91.28, 91.467, 91.653, 91.84, 92.027, 92.213, 92.4, 92.587, 92.773, 92.96, 93.147, 93.333, 93.52, 93.707, 93.893, 94.08, 94.267, 94.453, 94.64, 94.827, 95.013, 95.2, 95.387, 95.573, 95.76, 95.947, 96.133, 96.32, 96.507, 96.693, 96.88, 97.067, 97.253, 97.44, 97.627, 97.813, 98.0, 98.187, 98.373, 98.56, 98.747, 98.933, 99.12, 99.307, 99.493, 99.68, 99.867, 100.053, 100.24, 100.427, 100.613, 100.8, 100.987, 101.173, 101.36, 101.547, 101.733, 101.92, 102.107, 102.293, 102.48, 102.667, 102.853, 103.04, 103.227, 103.413, 103.6, 103.787, 103.973, 104.16, 104.347, 104.533, 104.72, 104.907, 105.093, 105.28, 105.467, 105.653, 105.84, 106.027, 106.213, 106.4, 106.587, 106.773, 106.96, 107.147, 107.333, 107.52, 107.707, 107.893, 108.08, 108.267, 108.453, 108.64, 108.827, 109.013, 109.2, 109.387, 109.573, 109.76, 109.947, 110.133, 110.32, 110.507, 110.693, 110.88, 111.067, 111.253, 111.44, 111.627, 111.813, 112.0, 112.187, 112.373, 112.56, 112.747, 112.933, 113.12, 113.307, 113.493, 113.68, 113.867, 114.053, 114.24, 114.427, 114.613, 114.8, 114.987, 115.173, 115.36, 115.547, 115.733, 115.92, 116.107, 116.293, 116.48, 116.667, 116.853, 117.04, 117.227, 117.413, 117.6, 117.787, 117.973, 118.16, 118.347, 118.533, 118.72, 118.907, 119.093, 119.28, 119.467, 119.653, 119.84, 120.027, 120.213, 120.4, 120.587, 120.773, 120.96, 121.147, 121.333, 121.52, 121.707, 121.893, 122.08, 122.267, 122.453, 122.64, 122.827, 123.013, 123.2, 123.387, 123.573, 123.76, 123.947, 124.133, 124.32, 124.507, 124.693, 124.88, 125.067, 125.253, 125.44, 125.627, 125.813, 126.0, 126.187, 126.373, 126.56, 126.747, 126.933, 127.12, 127.307, 127.493, 127.68, 127.867, 128.053, 128.24, 128.427, 128.613, 128.8, 128.987, 129.173, 129.36, 129.547, 129.733, 129.92, 130.107, 130.293, 130.48, 130.667, 130.853, 131.04, 131.227, 131.413, 131.6, 131.787, 131.973, 132.16, 132.347, 132.533, 132.72, 132.907, 133.093, 133.28, 133.467, 133.653, 133.84, 134.027, 134.213, 134.4, 134.587, 134.773, 134.96, 135.147, 135.333, 135.52, 135.707, 135.893, 136.08, 136.267, 136.453, 136.64, 136.827, 137.013, 137.2, 137.387, 137.573, 137.76, 137.947, 138.133, 138.32, 138.507, 138.693, 138.88, 139.067, 139.253, 139.44, 139.627, 139.813, 140.0, 140.187, 140.373, 140.56, 140.747, 140.933, 141.12, 141.307, 141.493, 141.68, 141.867, 142.053, 142.24, 142.427, 142.613, 142.8, 142.987, 143.173, 143.36, 143.547, 143.733, 143.92, 144.107, 144.293, 144.48, 144.667, 144.853, 145.04, 145.227, 145.413, 145.6, 145.787, 145.973, 146.16, 146.347, 146.533, 146.72, 146.907, 147.093, 147.28, 147.467, 147.653, 147.84, 148.027, 148.213, 148.4, 148.587, 148.773, 148.96, 149.147, 149.333, 149.52, 149.707, 149.893, 150.08, 150.267, 150.453, 150.64, 150.827, 151.013, 151.2, 151.387, 151.573, 151.76, 151.947, 152.133, 152.32, 152.507, 152.693, 152.88, 153.067, 153.253, 153.44, 153.627, 153.813, 154.0, 154.187, 154.373, 154.56, 154.747, 154.933, 155.12, 155.307, 155.493, 155.68, 155.867, 156.053, 156.24, 156.427, 156.613, 156.8, 156.987, 157.173, 157.36, 157.547, 157.733, 157.92, 158.107, 158.293, 158.48, 158.667, 158.853, 159.04, 159.227, 159.413, 159.6, 159.787, 159.973, 160.16, 160.347, 160.533, 160.72, 160.907, 161.093, 161.28, 161.467, 161.653, 161.84, 162.027, 162.213, 162.4, 162.587, 162.773, 162.96, 163.147, 163.333, 163.52, 163.707, 163.893, 164.08, 164.267]
            
a=numpy.array(a)
t=numpy.array(t)

mean = numpy.mean(a)
std = numpy.std(a)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(a,prominence=1)

pyplot.plot(a)
pyplot.plot(peaks,a[peaks],"o")
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXHhe.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is not clear what exactly is your question. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful, and do not forget to provide a <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve">minimal, complete, and verifiable example</a> of what you problem is, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: sorry this link got corrupted so here it is: [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @piterbarg just use the [shorthand link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) `[mcve]`